# В какой таблице битрикс хранит посты

Tags: mysql, битрикс

Фирма поменяла статус с ЗАО на АО, в связи с чем на сайте как в тексте так и в заголовках нужно поменять название, попробывал слить всю базу и залить заново, но выдаёт `ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 82: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

строка 82 и 83

```
INSERT INTO `b_agent` (`ID`, `MODULE_ID`, `SORT`, `NAME`, `ACTIVE`, `LAST_EXEC`, `NEXT_EXEC`, `DATE_CHECK`, `AGENT_INTERVAL`, `IS_PERIOD`, `USER_ID`) VALUES
(1, 'main', 100, 'CEvent::CleanUpAgent();', 'Y', '2015-05-15 00:00:18', '2015-05-16 00:00:00', NULL, 86400, 'Y', NULL),
```

По этому хочу попробывать перезалить текста и заголовке - но вот какую таблицу скачивать для изменения?

Answer (score 2):

Если информация хранится в инфоблоках, то это таблица *b_iblock_element*, можно попытаться произвести замену там. Но я бы рекомендовал делать это руками из админ. панели.

Так же заголовки(тег title) могут быть жестко установлены на страницах через

```
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("ЗАО Рога и Копыта");
```